# Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials of a Dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, lie-algebras, coxeter-groups

We want to compute [the Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%E2%80%93Lusztig_polynomial) of a Dihedral group $D_n$.

I understand that they are of the form $$(1,v,v,v^2,v^2,v^3,v^3,\cdots,v^k)$$ and am able to show it by hands in small cases, but I can't see a way to prove it all together!

Thanks!